# mkstemp() and fdopen() in Cygwin 1.7.28

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cygwin

In the course of building some C++-based code under Cygwin (1.7.28-2, 64-bit) with GNU GCC 4.8.2,  I ran into the following errors:

```
...
SortDetails.cpp: In function ‘FILE* create_tmpfile(const char*, char**)’:
SortDetails.cpp:127:20: error: ‘mkstemp’ was not declared in this scope
   fd = mkstemp(tmpl);
                    ^
SortDetails.cpp:133:24: error: ‘fdopen’ was not declared in this scope
   fp = fdopen(fd, "wb+");
...
```

The specific chunk of code that fails to compile is:

```
FILE *
create_tmpfile(char const* path, char** fileName)
{
  FILE* fp;
  int fd;
  char* tmpl;

  if ( path == NULL )
      {
          fileName = NULL;
          return tmpfile();
      }

  tmpl = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(path) + L_tmpnam);
  strcpy(tmpl, path);
  strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path), "/sb.XXXXXX");
  fd = mkstemp(tmpl);                        /* <----- here... */
  if(fd == -1)
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "unable to create temp file!\n");
          return NULL;
      }
  fp = fdopen(fd, "wb+");                    /* <----- ...and here */
  *fileName = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmpl) + 1);
  strcpy(*fileName, tmpl);
  free(tmpl);
  return fp;
}
```

(The results of `malloc` are being cast because this code is within a larger C++-based project.)

**Regression**

This code compiles and works successfully with GNU GCC 4.8.x on Linux hosts and with Clang/++ 5.0 under OS X.

**Environment**

I am using the following version of Cygwin:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 CygFoo-PC 1.7.28(0.271/5/3) 2014-02-09 21:06 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Here is the version of GCC I am using:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-2/src/gcc-4.8.2/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/cygwin64/gcc/gcc-4.8.2-2/src/gcc-4.8.2 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-math-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

**Questions**

1. Is there support for `mkstemp()` and `fdopen()` in GCC 4.8.2 for Cygwin?
2. If not, is there a package I can add or a library I can relatively easily compile to add support for these functions?
3. If not, are there alternatives to `mkstemp()` and `fdopen()` that I can make use of to replicate their functionality under Cygwin?

**Possible fix**

Here's a modified version of this function:

```
FILE *
create_tmpfile(char const* path, char** fileName)
{
  FILE* fp;
  char* tmpl;

  if ( path == NULL )
      {
          fileName = NULL;
          return tmpfile();
      }

#if defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(_WIN32)
  const char *cygwinPrefix = "/sb.";
  const char *cygwinTmpDir = "/tmp";
  char *cygwinTmplSuffix = (char *)malloc(1 + L_tmpnam);
  tmpnam(cygwinTmplSuffix);
  tmpl = (char *)malloc(1 + strlen(path) + strlen(cygwinPrefix) + strlen(cygwinTmplSuffix + strlen(cygwinTmpDir) + 1));
  strcpy(tmpl, path);
  strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path), cygwinPrefix);
  strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path)+strlen(cygwinPrefix), cygwinTmplSuffix + strlen(cygwinTmpDir) + 1);
  fp = fopen(tmpl, "wbx+"); /* we add the 'x' extension to apply the O_EXCL flag, to avoid a security hole described in the GNU C library docs */
  free(cygwinTmplSuffix);
#else
  tmpl = (char*)malloc(1 + strlen(path) + L_tmpnam);
  strcpy(tmpl, path);
  strcpy(tmpl+strlen(path), "/sb.XXXXXX");
  int fd = mkstemp(tmpl);
  if(fd == -1)
      {
          fprintf(stderr, "unable to create temp file!\n");
          return NULL;
      }
  fp = fdopen(fd, "wb+");
#endif
  *fileName = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmpl) + 1);
  strcpy(*fileName, tmpl);
  free(tmpl);
  return fp;
}
```

This is pretty ugly. If there is a way to use POSIX functions, I'd like to use them, if I can. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When compiling with `g++` 4.8.2 on Cygwin, I logged the expansion of macros in three cases:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -E -Dd foo.cpp > foo.log.c++11
$ g++ -ansi -E -Dd foo.cpp > foo.log.ansi
$ g++ -E -Dd foo.cpp > foo.log.noFlag
```

Comparing the logs was useful. There were "holes" in the `-std=c++11` and `-ansi` cases, while a block containing the `mkstemp()` declaration shows up in the "flagless" case. This let me zero in on the parts of the headers that were processed differently.

In the file `/usr/include/stdlib.h`, declarations of `mkstemp()` and some other functions are rejected if `__STRICT_ANSI__` is defined — such as when we use the compile-time flags `-ansi` and `-std=c++11`.

Likewise, in the file `/usr/include/stdio.h`, declarations of `fdopen()` will get skipped for the same reason.

The C++ headers `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>` both include the `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` headers and leave declaration of those two functions (among others) up to those two headers. So if we use `-ansi` and/or `-std=c++11` then those two functions will not be declared and we get the compile errors.

The solution that seems to work for the toy code samples is to undefine `__STRICT_ANSI__` before compiling:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -U__STRICT_ANSI__ foo.cpp
```

It's not clear what the side effects of this will be, but from googling, it seems like this is a common problem and a common fix applied by other developers who need to target Cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin has a Linux-like set of [Feature Test Macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html).  However, on Linux with C++, `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined unconditionally, essentially negating all such guards.  On Cygwin, we do *not* do this, meaning you actually have to respect the meaning of the various flags on C++ as well.

As noted, using any `-std=c++*` flag will define `__STRICT_ANSI__`, which is recognized by the macros.  Undefining that on the command line is incorrect.  Instead, either define the correct documented flag(s) for the functions you wish to use (in this case, `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` should cover both), or use `-std=gnu++*` flags instead (which, btw, do *not* define `_GNU_SOURCE`) to not declare ANSI compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was compiling git-crypt and encountered the same problem. The solution from the answer above worked except that it had to be deployed via 'make' and not via 'g++', like this:

```
make CXXFLAGS="-U__STRICT_ANSI__ -std=c++11"
```

Comment: had to remove `-U__STRICT_ANSI__`  because of: `warning: #warning "__STRICT_ANSI__ seems to have been undefined; this is not supported" [-Wcpp]`,    `make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11"` worked like a sharm.   (cygwin:3.4.9-1, git-crypt: 0.7.0)

Answer (score -1):

My pal Vincent cooked up a simple version that works with Cygwin. http://code.google.com/p/xpost/source/browse/src/lib/xpost_compat.c#113

It might not cover all cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

# include <windows.h>
# include <io.h>

int mkstemp(char *template)
{
    char *temp;

    temp = _mktemp(template);
    if (!temp)
        return -1;

    return _open(temp, _O_CREAT | _O_TEMPORARY | _O_EXCL | _O_RDWR, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
}
```

As for `fdopen`, I'm not sure. I'll have to do some research/thinking.